# How to handle OAuth2 user after login with Google in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I am using Spring boot and keycloak to implement user authentication. Now I've introduced google authentication, and currently I am facing the problem of handling authenticated user in spring boot. So, after user logins with google, in my application I want to check if the user already exists in database (if no, then I need to save it to db), or if the user exists, check if he has verified his email address. If email is not verified just throw exception. The problem I am facing is that customOAuth2UserService isn't called when user logins with google.

Here is my security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                        .loginPage("/auth/login/google") // This is the endpoint for initiating OAuth2 login
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.userService(customOAuth2UserService()))
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/registrationConfirm").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter)))
                .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService() {
        return new CustomOAuth2UserService(userRepository);
    }

}
```

And here is CustomOAuth2UserService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        try {
            saveOAuth2User(oAuth2User);
        } catch (AccountNotVerifiedException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
        return oAuth2User;
    }


    private void saveOAuth2User(OAuth2User oAuth2User) {
        String email = oAuth2User.getAttribute("email");
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()){
            User user = userOptional.get();
            if (!user.isEmailVerified())
                throw new AccountNotVerifiedException();
        }else {
            Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes();
            System.out.println(attributes);

            User user = User.builder()
 //                   .id(oAuth2User.getAttribute())
                    .email(email)
                    .firstName(oAuth2User.getAttribute("given_name"))
                    .lastName(oAuth2User.getAttribute("family_name"))
                    .enabled(true)
                    .emailVerified(true)
                    .role(Role.USER)
                    .build();

            userRepository.save(user);
        }
    }
}
```

It's implementation isn't finished, but nevertheless the loadUser method isn't called. I checked it with debugger and with logs.

Maybe you can help me to fix it, or advice some other solutions, that will help to handle Google authentication.

So, to summarise, I want to handle google authentication in my application. The authentication itself works, it save's user to keycloak, but I'd like to save it to postgres as well and handle some situations like not verified email or something else if needed.